# Can't start Goldendict to system tray on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, indicator, system-tray, goldendict

I've just tried out Kubuntu 18.04 and somehow I cannot start Goldendict to system tray on start up. It's so weird because when I run goldendict in terminal or from dash, it starts to system tray without problem. But only on start up it shows the whole window with a very long number (screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: If you want goldendict to autostart use `System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart > Add Program` In the GUI that appears, look under `Education > Miscellaneous`. I don't know why you see this weird long string in the search box by default. Did you set up your dictionaries correctly? Also, with goldendict *not* running, have you tried renaming `~/.goldendict` to `~/.goldendict.bak` and then starting `goldendict`? Perhaps something in your `~/.goldendict` is corrupted?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I remove the .goldendict directory and now everything is fine. Except one thing, that  it always drops down the File menu everytime it runs, but I can workaround by hiding the menu with Ctrl+M

Comment: Well, now it happens again, deleting .goldendict only helps one time.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem as well. If you dig into it deeper you'd notice goldendict starts (the same wrong way) even being removed from autostart! The only way to stop it from start on login is

1. remove from autostart
2. kill (not just close into tray, but kill like `pkill goldendict`)
3. relog/reboot

Why? Because the default (before you ever touch the setting) KDE start behavior is "restore previous session" (at least in 18.04)! And when it "restores" previouly running apps it supplies "-session XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXXXX" argument to those. Try running `goldendict -session hello` and you'll see it will start not into systray and with "hello" word in the search field. [Here is how it did start for me on login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrlFY.png) and [here is what I saw in pstree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y10tr.png).

Now to the fix. Go *System settings/Startup and Shutdown* and set *On Login=Start with an empty session*.

**DONT SET IT TO "RESTORE MANUALLY SAVED SESSION"!!**

I tried it and on relog there only was a black screen (probably because I left with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Bksp</kbd>). To fix that I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to a virtual console and changed *loginMode* to *default* in `~/.config/ksmserverrc` (it says "default" but the meaning is "empty session").

Thanks for posting your question so I didn't feel lonely dealing with it!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be fixed on KDE by adding`goldendict` to the line starting with `excludeApps`  in the file `~/.config/ksmserverrc`; for example

```
excludeApps=goldendict
```

See https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/issues/1041 for a similar discussion.